What Can Be Switched in the AnimationPlayer Dropdown?
I am reading about the gadget_inspection in librerama.
code: https://codeberg.org/Librerama/librerama
As attached images, when set to RESET, there is only one keyframe, but when I switch to pointer_move, there are two keyframes. (It took me some time to discover this. Until I figured it out, I was puzzled as to why there was only one keyframe.)
I accidentally discovered that I could switch this in the dropdown(As attached images), but what exactly did I switch? (I don't quite understand how the AnimationPlayer works in Godot.)




In the Animation Panel, the dropdown menu of the animation controls lets you browse the available animations for the AnimationPlayer Node currently selected. Whenever you create a new animation for a given AnimationPlayer, it will appear here. If you select an animation from the dropdown menu, you can view/edit its animation tracks in the Animation Panel.
You can read more about the animation features in the Godot docs.
